# javascript load in wordpress template issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I created a wordpress template for a customer and I used a plugin to allow registered users to customize his profile. The issue appears when I'm trying to change the profile photo, the modal windows that allow that don't charge!

Please see this picture: http://tattoobiter.com/custom.png

I tried to insert manually (in chrome console)

`<div id="um_umpload_single"></div>`

in `</div class="um-modal no-photo">` and it works correctly till refresh the page.

I think something of my template don't let javascript to charge correctly, but I can't understand what...

Please help!

I tried to insert the first div in the second with append jquery but don't work...

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: nop...it just don't work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, It seems wordpress have problems to charge javascript external scripts if don't have the "".